# how to save value ='val' where user ='username' in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have a function in `admin.py` which is generating a token i need to save that token to database. How to do that?

```
token = get_token(key,cert,salt,picval);
```

models.py file content below:
The token value is generated and stored in `token`

```
class GenerateCertificate(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.username)
```

How do I save the new generated token value to `token` field in database. where `username  = user1`

Answer (score 1):

To filter certificates by username you can use `username__username` lookup (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) about relationship filters). To update filtered record use `update`:

```
token = get_token(key,cert,salt,picval)
GenerateCertificate.objects.filter(username__username = "user1").update(token=token)
```